# Custom Element Web Component Shadow DOM Vendor Scripts/Elements

Tags: recaptcha, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

When working with [Custom Elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements) that leverage [Shadow DOM](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees), what is the official approach to injecting 3rd party scripts and elements such as [Invisible reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) which require scripts such:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`
```

for HTML elements such as a `<button>` to be leaded and reCAPTCHA to be rendered?

`shadowRoot` doesn't seem to have anything like `head`, is the script supposed to be added to the created `template`'s `innerHTML`? Or is a `<script>` to be appended to the shadowRoot via `appendChild` in `connectedCallback()`?  What is the official approach to working with 3rd party libraries within Shadow DOM? Loading the script on the page containing the rendered Custom Element doesn't seem to trigger a render due to Shadow DOM.

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <form>
        <button class="g-recaptcha" 
            data-sitekey="your_site_key" 
            data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
`;

class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    ...
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    ...
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *offical approach* because the solution depends on the 3rd party library implementation.

However, in the case of reCaptcha, the workaround is to expose the `<button>` in the normal DOM, and inject it in the Shadow DOM via the `<slot>` element.

```
class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} ).innerHTML= `
            <form>
                <slot></slot>
            </form>`                
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `                  
            <button
                class="g-recaptcha"
                data-sitekey="your_site_key"
                data-callback="onSubmit">Submit</button>`
        }
    })
```