# Rendering Google ReCaptcha in shadow dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, shadow-dom

We are getting one error on rendering the captcha:
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Seems the issue is ReCaptcha is not made to work in Shadow Dom. So is there any workaround for it.

In React I got a article saying render captcha outside of shadow root and use it inside shadow root by some reference. 
Here is the link: https://medium.com/@tomas_26986/using-recaptcha-with-react-and-shadow-dom-abfd19fa03a

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Element Web Component Shadow DOM Vendor Scripts/Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226529/custom-element-web-component-shadow-dom-vendor-scripts-elements)

Comment: This solution will work if we have one level of shadow dom. Our requirement is to build the captcha as reusable component. The captcha component then can be embedded into forms which is itself in a shadow dom. The solution require here is to render it outside all shadow dom and use it as a reference inside shadow dom. Is there anything which can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `RecaptchaVerifier` from the Firebase V9 SDK when using `signInWithPhoneNumber`.  I resolved this by creating a `<DIV>` at the `Document` level from within my web component as it does indeed seem that `ReCaptcha` doesn't work within Shadow DOM.

This bit of code should help you:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit';
import { customElement } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../libs/firebase-app.js';

@customElement('phone-auth-component')
export class PhoneAuthComponent extends LitElement {
  private recaptchaContainerId = 'recaptcha-container-global';

  firstUpdated() {
    // Ensure the div exists at the root level of the document
    this.ensureRecaptchaContainer();
    
    auth.languageCode = 'en';
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      auth,
      this.recaptchaContainerId,
      {
        size: 'invisible',
        callback: (response) => {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow phoneNumber verification
          console.log('reCAPTCHA solved, allow phoneNumber verification');
        },
      }
    );
  }

  ensureRecaptchaContainer() {
    // Check if the container already exists
    let container = document.getElementById(this.recaptchaContainerId);
    if (!container) {
      // Create a new div and append it to the body
      container = document.createElement('div');
      container.id = this.recaptchaContainerId;
      document.body.appendChild(container);
    }
  }

  // Add the rest of your component logic here...
  
  render() {
    // Your render logic here...
  }
}
```